# How do you find contracts on the blockchain matching a specific bytecode?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

I discovered a YouTube based scam where a fake Solidity tutorial instructs users to go into Remix and deploy a scam contract. The scam contract allows any address to withdraw the funds. It has fake comments that are hilarious, but it is really scary that this scam targets potential new people in the space.

How do I find the matching contracts from the compiled bytecode? I want to see on the blockchain which contracts match this so I can find the offending address that reaches out to claim.

If there a method in geth? What about a scanner? Maybe The Graph and a subgraph?

Should I just download the chain and query? The problem for me is chain bloat and syncing Ethereum will take forever.

Comment: The only way i can think of, without having to go through a hassle, would be that if you have the bytecode, you can deploy it and use the following: https://etherscan.io/find-similar-contracts

Comment: The problem with that would be you are spending hundreds in gas, and also looking like a scammer. I'm going to check on Polygon to see if similar.